# Hiding a Div on Desktop

Tags: display, desktop

I am building a product page on Shopify right now and am using the custom liquid block.

I built a table within this block for the desktop version of the site and it looks good to go, but I wanted to hide it on mobile. I successfully made that happen.

My issue is, now that I've also made a version of this for mobile, I am trying to hide it on desktop and am having zero success.

Am I missing something?

```
<table class="table1">
<h6 class="perkstitle">Why Order From Us?</h6>
<tr> 
<td class="perksind">Guarneteed to ship within 24 business hours</td>
<td class="perksind"> Ships directly from the manufacturer</td>
<td class="perksind"> Live customer service <a href="tel:16109414333">610-941-4333</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="mobileonly">
<p class="columnm">Hello</p>
<p class="columnm">Hello</p>
<p class="columnm">Hello</p>
</div>


<style>

.table1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.mobileonly {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.perkstitle {
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 35px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
color:black;
font-family: roboto;
text-align: center;
}

.perksind   {
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
font-family: roboto;
color: white;
background-color: #d59e0d;
border: solid;
border-color: #F1F0F0;
border-width: 5px;
padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px;

}

.columnm   {
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
font-family: roboto;
color: white;
background-color: #d59e0d;
border: solid;
border-color: #F1F0F0;
border-width: 5px;
padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px;
text-align:center;
line-height: 1.4em;

}

a {

color: white;
}

 .color-accent-1{
background-color: #E6E6E6; !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
.table1 {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {
.mobileonly {
  
  display: none;
  }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to close your media query, so do this and it will work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
  .table1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh and you should use 620px on both media queries to not have a completely blank page in between ;)
And close the second query with a } too.

Comment: You're welcome. Also consider using a clear indention, to make typos like this more obvious.